# how do i see results from print functions in gcloud?

Tags: python, gcloud

I am running a app in gcloud and there is a print function that i need to test. But I don't see anything in the terminal of gcloud so where is the print being printed to?

Comment: you can use file with `print()` like `fh = open(..., 'w')` `print(..., file=fh)`. Or you can redirect to file standard output which is used by `print()`, `sys.stdout = fh`. But you should rather use `logging` module instead of `print()` and save it in file.

Comment: Would be helpful if you can provide your use case, or a sample of the code you are using in order to know what you are expecting to print.
Nevertheless, as @furas mentioned, you would probably use the `print()` function.